# Unable to insert into a Feed object for a Custom Object

Tags: data-loader

I created a custom object (funding__c).  The associated posting object that got created is (funding__feed).  I'm using Informatica Cloud to load existing posts into the (funding__feed) object.

I get this error message during execution...

****Error loading into target [Funding__Feed] : Error received from salesforce.com.  Fields [].  Status code [CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY].  Message [entity type cannot be inserted: Feed: Funding].****

The user profile has full permission for the (funding__c) object.  I cannot assign permission to the FEED object. It must inherit from Parent Object.

Is the FEED object restricted to inserts and updates?

NOTE: We are doing this work because we are moving away from the OPPORTUNITY object to a custom object (Funding__c) and we need to salvage the posting activity that has occurred.

Comment: Are you able to post to the feed through the UI?

Comment: Yes I can post through the UI

Comment: @JosephCalabrese did you find a solution? I´m facing the same issue.